# Live updating line chart - Wont smoothly scroll off screen (wiggles)

Tags: d3.js

I have a line chart that I've built for displaying live data. I've read through https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ and I can get it to smoothly come on screen, but for the life of me, I cant get it to not 'wiggle' when I remove a datapoint and the corresponding line section from the screen.

Here is the section of code where I am updating the line and x-axis.

```
lineselection.datum(data)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr('d', line)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (xScale.range()[0]/data.length) + ',0)');

xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([time, start_time])
    .range([width - (margin * 2), 0])
    .clamp(true);

g.selectAll('.x.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .call(xAxis);
```

This produces a nice smooth line chart, where the new section of line is drawn outside of the clip-path, and then translated left into view. The x-axis scrolls along wonderfully with it.

In my data update method, I do a check to see if we are in my data view window (ie, we only want to view the last, say 60 seconds of data). If a point falls outside the time frame, we remove it, and update the start_time to reflect.

```
if ((time_frame + start_time) < time){
    for (d = 0; d < data.length; d++){
        if ((data[d].x + time_frame) < time){
            data.shift();
        }
        else{
            start_time = data[d].x;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am newer to both JS and D3, so please be gentle. Any help would be appreciated. Am I missing something obvious?

Here is a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3kn56mb7/2/

Edit. Added a jsfiddle.

Comment: could you may be create a fiddle with what you have ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3kn56mb7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3kn56mb7/12/

Thank you elias for helping me get to this!

Here is my draw function. I used selection.interrupt() to overcome a jitter.

```
function draw(){
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

var lineselection = svg.selectAll('.line_')
    .select('path');


lineselection.interrupt()
        .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + -(xScale.range()[0]/((duration / 100)-2)) + ',' + margin + ')');


if (data[0].x < time - time_frame - duration ){
        console.log('shift');
            data.shift();
}

lineselection.attr('d',line)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + margin + ')');



start_time = time - (duration * 2) - time_frame;

xScale.domain([time, time + (duration * 2) - time_frame])
    .range([width - (margin *2),0]);

d3.select('body')
    .select('svg')
    .select('g')
    .selectAll('.x.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .call(xAxis);
```

}

**EDIT**: I updated the code to reflect the selection.interrupt() change as well as included the entire draw function. I also updated the jsfiddle link.

**EDIT 2**: Fixed a margin error and updated the jsfiddle link.

**EDIT 3**: I came back to use this as a reference. I am looking at this bit of code a year later, and couldnt figure out why I did some weird math. I must have been breathing diesel fumes. In anycase, I redid the math so that it made sense (why was I dividing duration by 100 and subtracting 2)?

Changed this: https://jsfiddle.net/3kn56mb7/11/

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + -(xScale.range()[0]/((duration / 100)-2)) + ',' + margin + ')');
```

To this: https://jsfiddle.net/3kn56mb7/12/

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + -(xScale(data[data.length-1].x) -xScale.range()[0]) + ',' + margin + ')');
```

I am now taking the last data point every draw cycle, and getting its time (x value) and converting that to a position in the range. Then I subtract the max range out (width-margin*2). Make the difference negative so it moves left.

Comment: Yes, there's an unfortunate conflict between the update period and the transition period, which I also think is impossible to overcome. At least I came up with a similar solution in my project, where the transition time was reduced too, causing the chart to stop a little bit for every second. I'd recommend moving the axis accordingly, thus changing the transition duration on the last lines in your code, but if this is your preference, you should keep it this way.

Comment: I came up with the solution this morning when reading through d3 v4 documentation. selection.interrupt() interrupts all active transitions and cancels all queued transitions. worked perfectly.  thanks again!

Comment: Wow, that one is really beautiful!

Comment: I think the line chart itself - i.e. the path - still needs a vertical translation of 20 pixels because of the margin. You can add this value in the accessor function, but in my opinion it is more elegant to take care of it in the `transform` attribute of variable `lineselection`. Nothing tricky, just use `'translate(0,'+margin+')'` instead of `null`, and change the y coordinate of the translation inside the transition from `0` to `margin` as well.

Comment: I know it's been about a year, but I came back to this as a reference. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the JSFiddle, and the answer.

Comment: Great to see that you keep the answer updated to reflect the best current understanding!

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your data elements' indices are changing by removing the obsolete elements. I've faced the very same issue in a project of mine, and solved it in the following way:

I recommend that doing what you now in the transition in two separate steps:

- when removing the element, draw a new path with the new indices - do this immediately, without a transition, so the wiggling does not appear
- after this has been done, a transition can happen, which is then only a translation, during which no elements get deleted

Comment: This totally helped me understand what was going on. I thought I understood what was happening on https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/, but I didnt really get it until this post. I still havent exactly gotten it to work though, but I'm close.